# Why is there a space in this string when printed?

Tags: python, cs50, string-interpolation

There is a space after `Hello,`, and I don't understand why.

This code from CS50'S Python course and I didn't get how its output is `Hello,(space)David`, for example, when the input name is `David`.

```py
name = input("What is your name? ")
name = name.strip()
print(f"Hello, {name}")
```

How is there a space?

p.s. I guess that's so beginner question but I'm a beginner, so :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, it will be `Hello, David`

Comment: It should be `Hello`, a comma, a space, and `David`, assuming the name you enter is `David`.  Look at your string.  It's right there:  `f"Hello, {name}"`  It substitutes `David` for `{name}`, leaving you with `"Hello, David"`.  The `"Hello, "` portion is fixed.  The `{name}` part is replaced with `David`.

Comment: It's because there's a space in your f-string

Comment: First, tell us the input. Is it just `David`? Then show the exact output you get. Is the comma missing?

Comment: You can experiment with formatting. `print("Hello{name}")` lacks the comma and the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your space you are forcing to be there is right here in your f-string:

```py
print(f"Hello, {name}")
     #        ^
     #        |
     # this adds the space
```

The f-string (`f"string"` format string) says to print `"Hello, "` (with that space after the comma), followed by `{name}`, which is the variable `name` substituted directly into the f-string at that location. Notice that the double quotes (`""`) are around the entire thing. Contrast this to the other examples below.

If you wrote this instead, with*out* the format string, it would still have a space simply because Python automatically adds spaces between printed arguments:

```py
name = "David"
print("Hello,", name)
```

Output:

```
Hello, David
```

To force there to be *no* space, you'd have to force the separator to be an empty string by setting `sep=""` with*out* using the f-string, like this:

```py
print("Hello,", name, sep="")
```

...or, *with* using the f-string, but leaving the space out, like this:

```py
print(f"Hello,{name}")
     #       ^
     #       |
     #   no space
```

Both of those will output this:

```
Hello,David
```

Here is how the Python [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function works:

I can see why you'd be confused. Take note of the following:

1. This is **1** argument into the `print` function. Don't confuse the comma inside this string as being a comma that is separating multiple arguments into the `print` function:

   arg1 = the f-string `f"Hello, {name}"`

   ```py
   print(f"Hello, {name}")
   ```
2. This is **2** comma-separated arguments into the `print` function:

   arg1 = the string `"Hello,"`
   arg2 = the variable `name`

   ```py
   print("Hello,", name)
   # Note: this is the same. The space between arguments makes no difference.
   # This just looks uglier is all:
   print("Hello,",name)
   ```
3. This is **3** comma-separated arguments into the `print` function:

   arg1 = the string `"Hello,"`
   arg2 = the variable `name`
   arg3 = the dictionary keyword argument `sep=""`, where `sep` is a predefined and recognized dictionary keyword according to [the official documentation for the `print()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

   ```py
   print("Hello,", name, sep="")
   ```